# read .csv file into 1D array c#

Tags: c#, csv

I would like to convert this code from java to C#
I need to write line by line from csv and store it in an array?

```
String csvFile = "data.csv";
String line = "";
String cvsSplitBy = ",";
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) 
{

  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
  {

 // use comma as separator
 String[] data = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
 System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(data[0]) + "  "+data[1] +  "  "+data[2] );
  }

 } 
catch (IOException e) 
{
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what seems to be the problem..? also I would personally create a class that stores the fields as the same structure as the .csv file and create a List<T> and populate your data that way.. there are literally 1000's of examples online as well as `SO` that give numerous ways 1 can parse a .csv file please do a google search and edit this question to state what the problem is.

Comment: Ugh, in Java "[this class assumes that the default character encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileReader.html)". If you actually wanted that in C#, you would pass [Encoding.Default](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnste/2005/03/15/dont-use-encoding-default/) to your file I/O constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to  parse each record/row into array, this might help.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("maybyourfilepat\data.csv"))
{
   string line = sr.ReadLine();
   //incase if you want to ignore the header
   while (line != null) 
   {
       string[] strCols = line.Split(',');
       line = sr.ReadLine();
   }
}
```